# Unique Prime Ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_6]$ of Residual Characteristic 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I’m trying to find the unique prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_6]$ of residual characteristic 3, but I’m having difficulty finding it.

I computed that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_6]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x+1)$.
Therefore, let $P\subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_6]$ be a prime ideal, and $(3)\subset P$, I will show $1+\zeta_6\in P$, but I couldn’t…

Please let me know if there is any way I can solve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $(1+\zeta_6)(1+1/\zeta_6)=3$

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for the welcome. I'm trying hard to make sense of the equations in my head, and I'm really enjoying seeing everyone on Stack Exchange's solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stumbling block seems to be that $3$ is not prime in this ring. It factors as

$3=(-1)(i\sqrt3)^2.$

If $\omega$ is the unique sixth root of unity in the first quadrant of the Argand plane, then

$i\sqrt3=\omega(1+\omega)$

and therefore

$1+\omega=(i\sqrt3)\omega^5.$

Thereby $1+\omega$ lies in the actual prime ideal $(i\sqrt3)$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I computed to confirm that $(i√3)$ was a prime ideal! It is also interesting that 1+ζ belongs to it.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, this is part of a general pattern: for $\omega$ a primitive $2p$th root of unity, with $p$ prime (your $2\cdot 3$ case generalizes to $2\cdot p$), $\omega+1$ satisfies ${(x-1)^p-1\over (x-1)+1}=0$, so the product of $\omega^k+1$ over $k=1,3,5,\ldots,2p-1$ excluding $p$ itself is $p$. Further, the ratios of the those elements (in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$) are demonstrably *units*, so these all generate the same (prime) ideal, whose $p-1$ power (square, instead, for $p=2$) is $p\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thinking again here, how could this product be negative? It seems to consistvof complex conjugate factors.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Oop, of course, you're right! :) I am very often guilty of the off-by-one thing in $p$ versus $p-1$, etc. Thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: I'm getting it now, but to get $p$ I need to (1) use prmimtive $2p$-th roots and (2) allow $k$ to run through odd numbers up to $2p-1$ but skipping $p$, to capture selectively the primitive roots when $p$ is odd (for $p=2$ the claim holds and there is nothing to skip).

Comment: @OscarLanzi, ah, well, one confusion-lending thing is that the field extension by a $p$th root unity (for $p$ odd) is the same as for the $2p$th root of unity... So there's some book-keeping, ... I think that's all it really is... for the $p$ versus $2p$.

Comment: Corrected the claim to match my findings.